# Can I create hash index in ms sql without alter table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I want to add hash index to my SQL Server table. And I want to write something like that

```
CREATE TABLE index_data_compression.with_HASH_INDEX
(
    col1 int NOT NULL,
    col2 int,
    col3 int
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (col1)
)
WITH
(
    MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON,
    DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA
);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED  INDEX ix_hash_Column2_col3
ON index_data_compression.with_HASH_INDEX HASH ( col2, col3 )
WITH (
    PAD_INDEX = OFF,
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
    STATISTICS_INCREMENTAL = OFF,
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF,
    OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF,
    BUCKET_COUNT = 4
);
```

But the create doesn't work with hash index - I don't understand why?

```
ALTER TABLE [index_data_compression].[with_HASH_INDEX] 
ADD INDEX [ix_hash_Column2_col3] 
NONCLUSTERED HASH ([col2], [col3]) WITH (BUCKET_COUNT = 4)
```

I don't want use alter table.

Can I create hash index via CREATE COMMAND in SQL Server 2017+

Comment: *"I don't want use alter table."* Why not? That's, according to the documentation, how you create them on an **existing** table: [code sample for syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/indexes-for-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver15#code-sample-for-syntax)

Comment: @Larnu I've thought that create index always works but unfortunately it doesn't work with memory optimized tables

Comment: If you don't want to use `ALTER TABLE`, you'll just have to live with disappointment. `CREATE INDEX` can't be used to create hash indexes. You'll find that many, if not most operations on in-memory tables required `ALTER TABLE`. This is a conscious choice, to emphasize that creating indexes for in-memory tables is really quite different from adding them to disk-based tables -- the actual table structure and the (compiled) code accessing it need to change.

Comment: *"unfortunately it doesn't work with memory optimized tables"* correct, and the documentation I linked to, shows you that. Which is why I'm asking what you have against `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: Please check this link might your issues get resolved .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/guidelines-for-using-indexes-on-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-2014